# Free relational DB to output query in JSON

Tags: database, json, relational

I realized some data stored on a DB, accessed by a site I developped, would be more effective if they were turned into Json files -  avoiding acessing the db itself(I pay per API call!).
The data structure definitely allow that (they are quite static and severla table can be downloaded at once).

However, some table data are related to other table's data and I need a way to keep data consistency, something JSON by itself (essentailly text management) does grant me to do (human error in writing external Keys always present!).

Hence, I would need a (possibly) free, simple, open source DB to manage few table with some relation between them (os an ordinary relational DB), to be used to some query in Json format.

Is anyone aware of any such solution?

Nice to have: no installation of db manager + a GUI to explore tha data.

Thanks!

P.S.please let me know shouldn't I have been not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Download the firefox plugin SQLite Manager.

You're all set

Comment: Thanks Justin, but apparently SQLite Manager can't export query in JSON. .. or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hrm, I don't know of something off hand that will do that. You would have to use a scripting language to parse the results and build the JSON. There may be a tool to do this, I don't know. I will Google around tomorrow and let you know if I find something.